How to clear the binary mask?
I have obtained a binary mask using segmentation model in pytorch. I want to remove these small patches from the masks and make it clean. There should not be any misclassified pixels. The masks obtained are attached here.
1
2
I have used the following code, but binary masks are as it is.
ratio = 0.05
area = ceil(ratio * mask1.shape[0] * mask1.shape[1])  # Use ceil to calculate the area
mask1 = remove_small_objects(mask1, min_size=area)

I have made changes in the threshold also, but it didn't effect.
Anyone, please help me with the solution.
Thankyou

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Look into segmentation mask post processing and image manipulation with opencv. There are a lot of different techniques/approaches for this
